# Athena Access Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I know Athena can parse logs of other services (S3, ELBs, CloudFront) with ease.  How do I get logs on Athena itself? I'd like to see who uses Athena and resource consumption.

Comment: Cloudtrail logs will include some details on athena query executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation: Logging and monitoring in Athena

- Monitor Athena with AWS CloudTrail: provides a record of actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service in Athena
- Use workgroups to separate users, teams, applications, or workloads, and to set query limits and control query costs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/security-logging-monitoring.html